# Hibernate EntityListener with Guice

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice, entitylisteners

I am trying to Inject a class into my entity listener created by my jpa provider.  The following code throws a PersistenceException - unable to build hibernate SessionFactory (which I expected).  From my research it seems like jpa 2.1 supports dependency injection.  I am missing some type of binding/provides for guice to know about this class.  My guess is it has to be some type of run time binding.

```
public class EntityListener {

private SomeService service;

@Inject
public EntityListener(SomeService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

@PostLoad
public void load(Object o){
   //use service here
}
}
```